# after adding ssl to wordpress site css and js not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have installed the Wordpress and added SSL to my [https://www.misfitfoodies.in](https://www.misfitfoodies.in/) but css not working after adding https to url. folder structure is as given below with htaccss file

```
htdocs
|_______wordress
|_______other_folder
```

> ```
> htdocs .htaccss_file root folder
> ```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^misfitfoodies.in
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.misfitfoodies.in/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.misfitfoodies\.in$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wordpress/
RewriteRule (.*) /wordpress/$1
```

> ```
> wordress .htaccss_file wordress folder
> ```

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

**Table: wp_options**

```
option_id | option_name | option_value                 | autoload
_________________________________________________________________   
1         |siteurl      | https://www.misfitfoodies.in | yes
2         |home         | https://www.misfitfoodies.in | yes
```

What am I missing???

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the css and javascript are loaded with http instead of https.
This creates mixed content - some files are loaded with https while others are not.

Mixed content occurs when the initial HTML is loaded over a secure connection, but other resources (such as images, videos, stylesheets, scripts) are loaded over an insecure HTTP connection.

You should check the theme's header.php, functions.php and footer.php for http links are replace them with their https equivalent.

Otherwise you can also create an .htaccess redirect such as this one:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: after adding above two lines code The page isn’t redirecting properly :( @8octopus